# How to handle Airplay pair-setup request

Tags: rtsp, airplay

Observed that pair-setup response sends 32 byte string to iPhone with following header

RTSP/1.0 200 OK

Content-Type: application/octet-stream

Server: AirTunes/220.68

CSeq: 0

Content-Length: 32

what string it sends to iPhone? if anyone knows solution please share it to me, Thanks in advance.